# Basis of subspace U

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $$U=\{p\in \mathcal P_4(\mathbf R):p''(6)=0\}$$ Find a Basis for U.

My attempt at a solution was to start with a vector in that fell into the subspace. Such vectors would look like: $\frac {d^2}{dx}(a_4x^4 +a_3x^3 +a_2x^2+a_1x^1+a_0x^0)=(12a_4x^2+6a_3x^1+2a_2)$.

Evaluated at the root 6, would yield $12a_4(6)^2+6a_3(6)^1+2a_2=0$ which shows that once $a_4\ and\ a_3$ are fixed, we can solve for the last unknown so $a_2=-6a_4(6)^2-3a_3(6)$. Next, I substitute so, $12a_4x^2+6a_3x^1-12a_4(6)^2-6a_3(6)=0\;$ then $12a_4(x^2-36)+6a_3(x-6)=0.$

It is up to this point I feel like I understand what I have done. I've taken a basis of the superspace and have determined what the vectors in the subspace would look like. Given this and the general form, I created a dependence equation and substituted in order to solve for my two linearly independent vectors. So can I conclude that the set of vectors $\{x^2-36,x-6\}$ is a basis of my subspace? I think my math is correct and I feel like my basis comes naturally from what I'd think, as any polynomial of at most degree 4 after having its derivative taken twice would be at most degree two.

Is my solution correct? and is my logic sound?

Answer (score 1):

By your calculation, the coefficients of $p(x)\in U$ have the relations
$$a_2=-18a_3-216a_4,\quad\text{and }a_0,a_1,a_3,a_4\text{ are free variables.}$$
That is, $\dim(U)=4$ and it can be checked that
$$\{1,x,-18x^2+x^3,-216x^2+x^4\}$$
is a basis for $U$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain though the motivation for substituting into the initial polynomial?

Comment: I don't know how to explain, but my motivation is to focus on the free variables you have, and combine them with the use of the constraint equation.